# How to get all groups that a mail contact is a member of?

Tags: powershell

I want to get all groups that a mail contact is a member of.

Script :

```
get-mailcontact -resultsize unlimited | where-object {($_.PrimarySmtpAddress -like "*@domain.com")} | select name,alias, PrimarySmtpAddress |export-csv c:\temp\contact.csv -NTI
```

My desired output:

```
"Name","Alias","PrimarySmtpAddress","Mail Groups"
"John T.","john.t_contoso.com","john.t@contoso.com","Mail Group1;Mail Group2"
"Amy T.","amy.t_contoso.com","amy.t@contoso.com","Mail Group4;Mail Group5"
"tstcontact","tstcontact_contoso.com","tstcontact@contoso.com","Mail Group2"
```

thanks,

UPDATE :

Script :

```
$groups = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited
Get-Mailcontact -resultsize unlimited
Where-Object {($_.PrimarySmtpAddress -like "*@domain.com")} | 
Select-Object name, alias, PrimarySmtpAddress, 
    @{Name = 'MailGroups'; Expression = {
        $contact = Get-MailContact -Identity $_.Name  # or use $_.Name
        (Get-ADObject -Identity $Contact.DistinguishedName -Properties 'MemberOf').MemberOf -join ';'
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\contact.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

My output :

```
"Name","Alias","PrimarySmtpAddress","MailGroups"
"User1","user1","user1@contoso.com","CN=MailGroup1,OU=DISTRIBUTION,DC=contoso,DC=local;CN=MailGroup2,OU=DISTRIBUTION,DC=contoso,DC=local"
```

My desired output :

```
"Name","Alias","PrimarySmtpAddress","MailGroups"
"User1","user1","user1@contoso.com","MailGroup1;MailGroup2"
```

Comment: I believe you are over complicating this. By retrieving the `MemberOf` property from `Get-ADObject`, you will end up with a list of DistinguishedNames as you have noticed. To then get the Name for these groups, you will need a further `Get-ADGroup`... Also, `$contact = Get-MailContact ..` is redundant, because you are already selecting contacts from the earlier `Get-Mailcontact` call (after which you forgot to add a pipe symbol..)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this myself, but please try below

```
$groups = Get-Group
Get-Mailcontact -ResultSize unlimited | 
Where-Object {($_.PrimarySmtpAddress -like "*@domain.com")} | 
Select-Object name, alias, PrimarySmtpAddress, 
    @{Name = 'MailGroups'; Expression = {
        $contact = Get-Contact -Identity $_.DistinguishedName  # or use $_.Name
        ($groups | Where-Object {$_.Members -contains $contact}).Name -join ';'
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\contact.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thanks Theo,  I am assuming, I am getting it via Get-ADObject. I have updated my script.  How can I get an output with desired output? thanks